# Transparent WDS Bridging not working as expected NanoStation M5 devices

Tags: wireless, layer2

I desire to have a transparent bridge between two locations, so i bought these two UBNT devices and use as such:
Language: english, Country: nepal
Version: Nanostation M5, XW.v5.5.9, build 21734 (latest)

Setup:

PC#1: 172.31.1.1/16

|

NSM5#1 - WDS Bridge AP mode 172.31.2.1/16

...... (-50db indoor testing at this time, dbm is ~20 to keep not so hot))

NSM5#2 - WDS Bridge Station mode 172.31.2.2/16

|

PC#2: 172.31.1.2/16

- i can ping from PC#1 to both NSM5#1 and NSM5#2
- i can ping from PC#2 to both NSM5#1 and NSM5#2
- i can web manage from PC#1 to both NSM5#1 and NSM5#2
- i can web manage from PC#2 to both NSM5#1 and NSM5#2
- from PC#1 i can not ping PC#2. (but the arp request is correct and sends ICMP via wireshark, PC#2 does not see the ICMP)
- from PC#2 i can not ping PC#1.  (but the arp request is correct and sends ICMP via wireshark, PC#1 does not see the ICMP)
- I have disabled IP Auto Alias, STP, Discovery and CDP to make the wireshark packets less. I do see a proprietary UBNT "LOOP" packet at some regular interval, i supose to detect in the bridge has a loop or not. It would be nice to disable this, in order to easier debug this issue.
- there is no overlapping networks defined in the windows 7 PCs being used.

Appreciate your timinely help to get this simple transparent bridge to work. Strange the ARPs work, but the packets do not seem to be transparently bridged?

Here is pics of the NSM5-AP:
[image: NSM5.Wireless.Tab.AP]
[image: NSM5.Network.Tab.AP]
Here is pics of the NSM5-Station:
[image: NSM5.Wireless.Tab.Station]
[image: NSM5.Network.Tab.Station]

Comment: Do you have any reason other than blind devotion to defaults that you are using /16? If you love those particular numbers, /22 would cover 172.31.0.1-172.31.3.254...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a variety of setting changing, i discovered that the real culprit was Norton firewall. Setting up trust exception for the opposite MAC fixed this issue.

The only other issues have also been with Java 8 not allowing me to see airView, because UBNT does not have a valid cert in the web server. I had to back down to java 7.x and set security to medium.

Thank you. but this question is answered by myself.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.